# java - execution of program

Tags: java, data-structures

I am currently learning how to program and i have a program I am trying to add a functionality to. I was wondering if you could tell me where the desired code need to go in order to execute properly. thank you

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// GolfApp2.java                         
//
// Allows user to enter golfer name and score information.
// Displays information ordered by score.
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
import java.util.Scanner;
import ch08.trees.*;
import support.*;       // Golfer

public class GolfApp2 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner conIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name;          // golfer's name
    int score;            // golfer's score

    BSTInterface<Golfer> golfers = new BinarySearchTree<Golfer>();
    Golfer golfer;
    int numGolfers;

    String skip;  // Used to skip rest of input line after reading integer

    System.out.print("Golfer name (press Enter to end): ");
    name = conIn.nextLine();
    while (!name.equals(""))
    {
      System.out.print("Score: ");
      score = conIn.nextInt();
      skip = conIn.nextLine();      

      golfer = new Golfer(name, score);
      golfers.add(golfer);

      System.out.print("Golfer name (press Enter to end): ");
      name = conIn.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The final results are");

    numGolfers = golfers.reset(BinarySearchTree.INORDER);
    for (int count = 1; count <= numGolfers; count++)
    {
      System.out.println(golfers.getNext(BinarySearchTree.INORDER));


    }
  }
}
```

**This is the code needed to add**

```
int countLess ( BinarySearchTree<Golfer> tree, Golfer maxValue )
{
    BSTNode<Golfer> maxNode = tree.root;
    BSTNode<Golfer> minNode = tree.root;
    int count  = 0;
    //Traverse Right Sub tree
    while(maxNode!=null)
    {
        if( maxNode.getInfo() < maxValue){
            count ++;
        }
        maxNode = maxNode.getRight();

    }

    //Traverse Left subtree
    while(minNode!=null)
    {
        if( minNode.getInfo() < maxValue){
            count ++;
        }
        minNode = minNode.getLeft();
    }

    return count;

}
```

**another**

```
Golfer min(BinarySearchTree<Golfer> tree) {
    BSTNode<Golfer> minNode = tree.root;
    if (minNode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    while (minNode.getLeft() != null) {
        minNode = minNode.getLeft();
    }
    return minNode.getInfo();
}
```

Thanks again. help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The code you want to be added, just a function add them in the same class and call them whenever you want.

Comment: The best way to learn is by trying something that doesn't work and making guesses about what went wrong! As long as you back up your changes, there's no harm in experimenting.

Comment: These are new behaviors (methods), so add them after the main method and you can call them directly by just passing the right arguments

Answer (score 0):

Just add the code inside your GolfApp2 class. It is just a function u can call it any where with GolfApp2 object.

```
public class GolfApp2 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
     //Code
     // call thoes methods here by creating object to the class
     GolfApp2 obj = new GolfApp2();
     int returnedValue = obj.countLess (param1,param2);
  }
  int countLess ( BinarySearchTree<Golfer> tree, Golfer maxValue )
  {
    //code
  }
  Golfer min(BinarySearchTree<Golfer> tree) {
   //code
  }
```

}